# Why does my phone only turn on when it's plugged in?

Tags: wifi, iphone

My iPhone 4 doesn't turn on unless it's plugged in. When it is plugged in, it briefly shows the Apple logo and then shows my lock screen. Where it should say Verizon and show how much signal I have, it only says searching. It also says my percentage is at 100% but I know it's really somewhere around 30-40% because that's how much charge it had before it turned off on me. Also, when I try turning on the wifi it tells me that the wifi networks are not available, but I have the wifi working at home. What does this mean, or what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

A common solution to this kind of problem is a complete restore (possibly in DFU mode). Before proceeding, make a backup of the entire content of your iPhone via iTunes or iCloud.
Then, download the latest firmware available via iTunes. Charge the battery entirely before the restore, just to be sure that the iPhone won't shut down during the process.
Proceed by putting the iPhone in DFU; let then iTunes do the rest. 
I suggest you to **DO NOT** restore your iPhone from backup after finishing. Test everything, including Wi-fi connection. Install an app that shows you the actual battery cycles. Maybe replacing the battery could do the trick. If possible, try to connect to different hotspot; if the iPhone could not connect, maybe another problem is in the antenna.
Let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a reset?

From Apple Support:

> **How to reset**
>
> You should reset your device as a last resort and only if you can't restart it.
>
> To reset, press and hold both the Sleep/Wake and Home buttons for at least 10 seconds, until you see the Apple logo.

Support link with pictures: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1430

If that fails: Plan B is to take it to the Verizon store or Apple store.

Answer (score 0):

i suspect the battery connecter needs soldered back on the board.